# Imagick doesn't render svg opacity properly

Tags: php, svg, opacity, imagick

I need same output from Inkscape and Imagick.

This is the expected result, exported from Inkscape.

[image: corect image]

However, the PHP code below outputs the following faulty result.

[image: wrong image]

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
$im = new Imagick();

$im->setResolution(400,400);
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$im->readImageBlob(str_replace(array("color1", "color2"), array("yellow", "blue"), file_get_contents("img.svg")));

$im->setImageFormat("png");
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo $im;
?>
```

**SVG code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="400">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" />
<path d="M250 150 L150 350 L350 350 Z" opacity="0.9" fill="color1" />
<path d="M150 50 L50 250 L250 250 Z" opacity="0.9" fill="color2" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use Imagick? It's more easy to do with real SVG programs.

Comment: I tried it on Windows 7 64bit 2.3.0 same issue. On linux with 3.1 it works like it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already fixed in current version of Imagick.

Answer (score 1):

What version of PHP and ImageMagick are you running? Please share the relevant output of `phpinfo()`. Could [this ImageMagick bug](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15058) be affecting you? Or if you're not up to date, could another ImageMagic bug be affecting you?

**EDIT:** I don't have easy access to a server with PHP's ImageMagick libraries installed at the moment, but if I find one, I'll test the code provided and post my results.

**EDIT2:** Looks like [others have the same issue](http://www.devcomments.com/SVG-to-transparent-PNG-with-imagick-to225822.htm), unless that forum post was also yours...

According to [this forum post](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=230530), you could try:

```
$im->setImageFormat("png32");
```

One person reported that worked, but another said it did not...

Comment: PHP version => 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2
imagick module version => 2.1.1-rc1

Comment: @Jan: Thanks. I posted a few more suggestions. Is this the stock PHP/imagick that's installed via Ubuntu's `apt-get`? What version of Ububtu? I can set up a virtual machine and try this for you on my end. I'm often in [the PHP chat room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60/php) if you want to talk this through.

Comment: i use ubuntu 10.04 lucid lynx, imagick and php were installed by synaptic (apt frontend). I also tested it on hosting with PHP Version 5.3.3 and imagick module version 2.3.0

Comment: @Jan: Sorry, it was a crazy day and I wasn't able to test this for you. I'll try this weekend. Maybe somebody else will chime in with a more definite solution.

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape uses the not ubiquitously supported `opacity` property. Use `fill-opacity` and `stroke-opacity` instead.

Comment: Worth knowing, but I've tried replacing opacity with fill-opacity and it makes no difference to this example.